# Bipolar NPN transistor does not work as expected in simple circuit

Tags: switching, npn

I need simple button in Raspberry circuit to force wake up on GPIO3 which is shared with I2C and shutdown on GPIO4. So I have cascade of inverting NPN bipolar and MOSFET. The circuit is pretty simple.

[image: Shutdown/wake up circuit]

When button is open then Q102 should be closed and leave SCL untouched. Q101 should be opened and gate Q102 should have 0V. But I see Q101 behaves as non-inverting, collector Q101 follows surprisingly Q101 base voltage. I tried to measure Q101 if is non-broken but I detected expected impedance on pins. It is pretty small package SOT-323 so not easy to get reliable results. I even resoldered but no progress. Currently PCB SMD pins are broken so I cannot investigate any more.

I put it in SPICE and it also think that it should work. I suspected if emitter is really grounded so I have R103 on emitter pin, R102 simulates button.

[image: SPICE simulation]

Large R103 does not prove suspicion as when R102 = 100 ohm then Vc is still Vcc. What is definitely different is Vb at Q101 because it was almost Vcc when button opened. SPICE offers CCA 640mV.

[image: SPICE for case when button opened]

Note: tested it also with RPI unplugged and Vcc 5V. Behaves the same way as with RPI and Vcc 3.3V.

Do you think the issue is broken Q101 even seems ok or am I keep doing some stupid mistake in design?

Comment: Are you using a 4-pin BJT with IC substrate included?

Comment: No, normal SOD-323. Bottom schema I made just for simulation. I did not find in Kicad library model related to Spice a classic 3 pin NPN model. I used sumulation first time so I'm not experienced how pins match between Spice and Kicad models so I used one targeted to simulation.

Answer (score 0):

> But I see Q101 behaves as non-inverting, collector Q101 follows surprisingly Q101 base voltage

If the real circuit is as per the schematic, then the voltage on C102 should never go above 0.7V.  What is the voltage you see here, in both cases of switch state (with switch open, and switch closed)?

> Currently PCB SMD pins are broken so I cannot investigate any more.

That is a worry.  Perhaps the PCB tracks/pin were already broken before and was the cause of the original problem?

Comment: C102 voltage was almost Vcc (3.3V or 5.1V). 0.7V max. offers SPICE as well. I do not think tracks were broken, I suspected short circuit because of too much solder paste so I resoldered but it did not fix problem. Finally I pushed to transistor with probes to measure voltage on small pins and it broke two pads.

Comment: "C102 voltage was almost Vcc (3.3V or 5.1V)."  Is that with switch SW101 OPEN or CLOSED?

Comment: It is in original text. When SW101 opened then C102 voltage almost Vcc. I suspected if emitter has contact to ground as noted.

Comment: It was not clear in your original text what the voltage at C102 was under the two specific conditions I mentioned: 1. SW101 OPEN.  2. SW101 CLOSED.   You did say "collector Q101 follows surprisingly Q101 base voltage" but that does not mention the state of the switch.  You did not mention the **measured voltage*** at the Q101 base.

Comment: As I mentioned, C102 reaching Vcc indicates a problem.  That problem could be any of the following:  1. Q101 emitter is not connected to pad.  2. Q101 base is not connected to pad.  3. Q101 is internally broken (open ckt C to E).  All 3 cases cause Q102 to turn ON via R104.

Comment: Suggest checking D101, as follows:  1. is it installed correctly, 2. is it broken, or 3.  is it leaky?

Comment: I somehow hacked board and resoldered new transistor. It works now, Vbe is approx 0.7V. I remeasured quickly original transistor and it is apparently somehow broken but not as short circuit. Measured P-N (base-emitter, base-collector) "diodes" have above 1kohm in both directions. Even multimeter says ok then new transistor has "logical" values.